# import tensorflow throws ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, tensorflow

i have installed `tensorflow` in `virtualenv` as well as regular system install and added all the required directories to Path
i am using `python 3.6.0`
installed tensorflow cpu only

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused- 
import
File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 59, in 
<module>
from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 
6, in <module>
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in 
<module>
from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: did you activate the environment?

Comment: Can this assist: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17393 ?

Comment: I don't know the correct answer in windows but in Ubuntu I did not install protobuf so i install it and it worked you can try `pip install protobuf==3.6.0` maybe this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Please upgrade your **`Python Version`** from **`3.6.0`** to **`3.6.1`** and your issue will be resolved.

For more information, please refer [Github Issue 1](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/5046#issuecomment-439736098) and [Github Issue 2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21967#issuecomment-441609972)